# Problems to indicate the tick marks in the X Axis

Tags: r, plot, axis

I am using this code to create a histogram in R:

```
hist(Variable, breaks=12, main = "Global Active Power", xlab = "XName", xlim=c(0,6) , ylim=c(0,1200))
axis(side=1, at=seq(0, 6, by=2))
axis(side=2, at=seq(0, 1200, by=200))
```

I want to have in the Axis X values at 2, 4 and 6. Theoretically and as far as I have read, the sentence: `axis(side=1, at=seq(0, 6, by=2))` should be enough, nonetheless I still have in the axis X the following values-> 1,2,3,4,5,6

Is there something else that I am not seeing?

Comment: Use the argument `xaxt = "n"` in `hist`: `hist(Variable, breaks=12, main = "Global Active Power", xlab = "XName", xlim=c(0,6) , ylim=c(0,1200), xaxt="n")`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. This details was driving me crazy. Thank you so much again.